# ShowDialog not blocking parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

This is a snapshot of the code I have

```
  Login form = new Login();
  form.ShowDialog();
  SomeMethod();
```

I want it to run `SomeMethod()` only when the login form is closed, but that does not seem to be the case.

I have a button inside the login form but whenever the button is clicked, it just exists the form and executes `SomeMethod()`. I did not call `this.Close()` anywhere in the login form, so I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Not sure what is the issue. The code you've shown will execute after the form is closed, which is the expected behavior. If the question is why the form is closed when you click a button, most likely the button has the [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) property set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a Form usin `ShowDialog()` it will exit whenever a DialogResult is found (most probably some of Login buttons have DialogResult property set). If you want to SomeMethod() be executed only under some circumstances then you have to manage that:

```
  Login form = new Login();

  if(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
       SomeMethod();
  }
  else
  {

  }
```

If you don´t want the form to close then open with `Show()` method and do whatever you need inside Login form.

Comment: Would using the show method freeze the parent form too? Becuase that's kinda important.

Comment: the Show() method will not freeze your parent form

Comment: if you want SomeMethod run only when some button is presed on Login then you have to asign a specific DialogResult to the close button and then do something with it

Comment: I want to not only prevent SomeMethod from running but also block the parent form completely. That includes the UI and the execution.

Comment: my suggestion is open with ShowModal in true and manage DialogResult